# How to improve the variable range for large integer number?

Tags: c

Large integer number is showing incorrect output even after using long in bellow code, but still it is showing incorrect result. How I can improve?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    void main()
    {

     long a, b, result;
     a=1234;
     b=19887815769532909;
     result= (0.5)*(a+b)*(a+b+1)*b;
     printf("%d", result);
     getch();

    }
```

but output is showing something like : -2147483648

I think I am doing something wrong with variable with large number.
I have also tried int long but failed.

Please help.

Comment: `19887815769532909` requires a 64-bit integer.

Comment: . . . but `19887815769532909` (effectively) cubed requires a bigint library.

Comment: `long result` cannot represent every possible integer.  It has a limited range exceed by `(0.5)*(a+b)*(a+b+1)*b`.  Try `double result = (0.5)*(a+b)*(a+b+1)*b; printf("%e\n", result);`

Comment: . . . although the purpose of the `double 0.5` is unclear in this context. Did you want a `double` result? Otherwise, better to halve a big integer.

Comment: If you're printing a `long`, you need to use `%ld` and not just `%d`.  However, you also have problems because your value is too big to fit into a `long` (or, indeed, a `long long` on most machines).  But you're exacerbating the problem by using an incorrect conversion specifier in the format.  Don't forget to print a newline too!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you need to use `long` or `long long` in your calculations. Moreover, the statement `result= (0.5)*(a+b)*(a+b+1)*b;` is causing integer overflow which is why a negative value is being printed to the console(despite using `%lld` as a format specifier. You can look at the ranges of the integer variants [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155784/range-of-values-in-c-int-and-long-32-64-bits). If possible you should also check for integer overflow in your calculations, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633661/how-to-check-integer-overflow-in-c).

But if you want to perform operations on integers bigger than the range provided by standard C primitives, you might want to implement it on your own using character or integer arrays(converting high school methods into code). There are lots of tutorials about it.

I hope this helps.