# How can I safely add and clamp a signed integer in C?

Tags: c, integer, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow, signed

I have a value, of type `signed int`, which is always clamped between, for example, ±1073741824 (2^30). I should be able to safely add or subtract any arbitrary value, and if the sum/difference is outside the range it is *clamped* (any value above the maximum maps to the maximum, and any value below the minimum maps to the minimum). I have the following:

```
signed int Min(signed int X, signed int Y) {
    return X < Y ? X : Y;
}
signed int Max(signed int X, signed int Y) {
    return X > Y ? X : Y;
}
signed int X;
void UpdateX(signed int Delta) {
    X = Min(Max(X+Delta, -(1<<30)), (1<<30));
}
```

However, if Delta and/or X is sufficiently large or small that the value overflows or underflows, this invokes [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because there is a `signed int` overflow before the clamping. One solution is to use a larger integer type temporarily, but this is not an option for other cases where the largest available type is already being used. How can I safely add then clamp a `signed int` without risking invoking undefined behavior?

Comment: @Exampleperson If X is the maximum 1073741824 and if Delta is also 1073741824, then the sum will be 2147483648 which is beyond the integer maximum and signed integer overflow is undefined

Comment: As a side note, if you want your type to be 32 bit in size, use int32_t, not int.

Comment: @Exampleperson Casting to unsigned int and casting back will remove the undefined behavior but I am guessing it will still give incorrect results if overflow occurs

Comment: @Exampleperson Then the result will be 0 instead of the correct maximum

Comment: Simple answer for 64-bit processes:  convert 32-bit inputs to `int64_t`, do the calculation as `int64_t`, compare, and clamp.  Then downcast to `int32_t`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle they have said that it is not an option as they may be using the largest integer available.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I thought of that, but what about *other* cases where I am already using the largest available integer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right to worry about overflow.  The obvious techniques for checking for overflow detect it *after* it's happened, which is of course too late, if there's any undefined behavior involved.

The standard technique is to rearrange the test.  Rather than saying:

```
if(X + Delta > MAX) { whoops! it overflowed; }
```

subtract `Delta` from both sides so you have

```
if(X > MAX - Delta) { whoops! it overflowed; }
```

Of course you also have to consider the possibility that `Delta` is negative.  So in your case I believe something like this will do it:

```
#define MAX (1<<30)

void UpdateX(signed int Delta) {
    if(Delta >= 0) X = (X <=  MAX - Delta) ? X + Delta :  MAX;
    else           X = (X >= -MAX - Delta) ? X + Delta : -MAX;
}
```

See also [How to check for signed integer overflow in C without undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633661)

See also [Question 20.6b](http://c-faq.com/misc/intovf.html) in the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/).